# How can I see a preview of pictures in a zip or rar file in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, zip, rar

Xubuntu has a very nice feature; previews (of pictures) in zip files in Thunar file browser.

How can I have this in Nautilus / Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this count exactly as "preview", anyway **File Roller** is the software used to open archive files in Nautilus (actually the **Nautilus extension of File Roller**, which depends on it).
Without that it is possible to extract/compress files and so on, but not to preview them in a GUI.

Once an archive is opened with it, it is possible to double click images inside an archive, this will open them in the default image viewer.

File Roller wasn't installed by default in my case.

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/FileRoller